# python import from parent dictory

Tags: python

I have a python file I want to import that is one directory up. How do I import it?

Here is my folder structure:

```
➜  testing ls -R
subfolder       toImportFrom.py

./subfolder:
toImportTo.py
➜  testing
```

What code should I put in the file `toImportTo.py` so that I can import from `toImportFrom.py` without using absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

import mymodule #mymodule is the file name you are trying to import from parent directory
```